# Attempting to make a stack ADT in C. Can't get the output I want from it

Tags: c, stack, adt

So we have been asked to make our own stack ADT for C that stores double precision floating point numbers. I made a very basic ADT with the basic stack functions (isEmpty,push,pop). Anyways, I decided to test out my ADT in the main, by creating 3 variables, and pushing them on the stack. Then I wanted to see what the top element was, but the output I am getting is very strange.

This is all the output I'm receiving:

```
(lldb)
```

The top SHOULD point to the variable result,and print that value, but the above is all I'm getting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// create a new structure for stack ADT.

struct double_stack{
  double * array;
  int stackCapacity;
  int numOfObjects;
  int top;
};

//creating a new empty stack.

struct double_stack *newStack(){

  struct double_stack*  new_Stack= malloc(sizeof(struct double_stack));

  //stack has a capactiy to store one element as default, and has 0 number of objects.

  new_Stack->stackCapacity = 1;
  new_Stack->numOfObjects = 0;
  new_Stack->array = malloc(sizeof(new_Stack->stackCapacity));

  //top points to -1 to show the stack is empty. When its not empty,it will point to 0,so an element can be placed at that index etc.

  new_Stack->top = -1;

  return new_Stack;
}


//check to see if stack is empty. Returns 1 if true. 0 if false.
int isEmptyStack(struct double_stack *this){

  //if the attribute pointed in the condition below is true,then stack is empty.
  if(this->numOfObjects==0 && this->top==-1){
    return 1;
  }
  else{
    return 0;
  }

}

//push an element onto the stack.

void push(struct double_stack * this, double element){

  this->stackCapacity++; //stack capacity is increased by 1 to make space for next element to be pushed on.

  this->numOfObjects++; //number of elements increased by 1.

  this->array[++this->top]=element; // the prefix ++ operator increments the top index before it is used as an index in the array (i.e., where to place the new element).

}

//this method pops an element off the stack. If stack is empty,the exit command quits the function. It returns the element to be popped ,because usually we need to perform some operation on the element.

double pop(struct double_stack*this){
  if(isEmptyStack(this)){
    printf("%s","Error:Cannot pop element from empty stack!");
    return -1;
  }

  return this->array[this->top--];
}


int main() {
  struct double_stack * s = newStack();
  double a = 5;
  double b = 10;
  double result=a+b;

  push(s,a);
  push(s,b);
  push(s,result);

  printf("%d",s->top);
}
```

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(new_Stack->stackCapacity));` you're missing a `* sizeof(double)` in there. Your initial allocation size for the array is exactly the size of one **`int`**. And since I see no evidence of any expansion algorithm, even if you fix that, any attempt to push more than one element will not work either.

Comment: Ex: `malloc(new_Stack->stackCapacity * sizeof(double))`

Comment: It's not causing you an actual problem, but do consider that your `top` and `numOfObjects` fields appear to be redundant.  It would be better to use just one, and thereby both reduce the amount of bookkeeping needed and avoid the possibility of internal inconsistency arising.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you can't increase the capacity of the stack dynamically and if you want to do so you need to use realloc.The capacity of the stack should be predefined or else you need to use linked list instead of using an array. Here is your working code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// create a new structure for stack ADT.

struct double_stack{
  double * array;
  int stackCapacity;
  int numOfObjects;
  int top;
};

//creating a new empty stack.

struct double_stack *newStack(int size){

  struct double_stack*  new_Stack= malloc(sizeof(struct double_stack));

  //stack has a capactiy to store one element as default, and has 0 number of objects.

  new_Stack->stackCapacity = size;//this is better way 
  new_Stack->numOfObjects = 0;
  new_Stack->array = malloc(sizeof(double)*new_Stack->stackCapacity);//size of the     //array must be declared here that is the capacity of the stack

  //top points to -1 to show the stack is empty. When its not empty,it will point     //to     0,so an element can be placed at that index etc.

  new_Stack->top = -1;

  return new_Stack;
}


//check to see if stack is empty. Returns 1 if true. 0 if false.
int isEmptyStack(struct double_stack *this){

  //if the attribute pointed in the condition below is true,then stack is empty.
  if(this->numOfObjects==0 && this->top==-1){
    return 1;
  }
  else{
    return 0;
  }

}

//push an element onto the stack.

void push(struct double_stack * this, double element){

  //this->stackCapacity++; //you cant increase the size of the array
  //put a check here if the stack is full
  if(this->top==(this->stackCapacity-1))
    printf("Stack is full\n");
  else{
    this->numOfObjects++; //number of elements increased by 1.

    this->array[++this->top]=element; // the prefix ++ operator increments the top     index before it is used as an index in the array (i.e., where to place the new element).
  }
}

//this method pops an element off the stack. If stack is empty,the exit command quits     the function. It returns the element to be popped ,because usually we need to     perform some operation on the element.

double pop(struct double_stack*this){
  if(isEmptyStack(this)){
    printf("%s","Error:Cannot pop element from empty stack!");
    return -1;
  }

  return this->array[this->top--];
}


int main() {
  struct double_stack * s = newStack(5);
  double a = 5;
  double b = 10;
  double result=a+b;

  push(s,a);
  push(s,b);
  push(s,result);

  printf("%f\n",s->array[s->top]);//this will print the last element on the stack
}
```